# Paging in SQL, how to use row number in where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to use the row numbers from MSSQL in the where clause of my SELECT query (in a stored procedure) however it won't let me reference that column in the where clause. How would you usually go about such a thing?

I'm trying the following (which doesn't work):

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [dtd]) AS row_num, [data]
FROM dbo.Reports INNER JOIN dbo.Types
WITH (NOLOCK)
ON dbo.Reports.type = dbo.Types.id
WHERE [dbo].[Reports].[Id] = @Id AND (row_num < (@page - 1) * 30) AND (row_num > @page * 30)
ORDER BY [dtd] DESC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `CTE`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [dtd]) AS row_num, [data]
    FROM dbo.Reports INNER JOIN dbo.Types
    WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON dbo.Reports.type = dbo.Types.id
    WHERE [dbo].[Reports].[Id] = @Id 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE 
WHERE (row_num < (@page - 1) * 30) AND (row_num > @page * 30)
ORDER BY [dtd] DESC
```

Comment: I haven't heard of a CTE, i'll try it and if it works shall certainly be reading up on them!